# Unable to scan barcode using Google vision api

Tags: android, xamarin, google-vision, gs1-128

I have a functionality to scan QR as well as barcode (GS1 128) format in two seperate screens. I am able to scan QR code however my `ReceiveDetections(Detections detections)` not detecting Barcode. Strange, I trying setting `.SetBarcodeFormats(Barcode.AllFormats)` and it detected `Code-128` but cant get it to detect `GS1-128 (UCC/EAN-128)`. `ReceiveDetections` is called but `barcodes` is null.

Below is my code:

```
_barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
         .SetBarcodeFormats(Barcode.AllFormats)
         .Build();
_cameraSource = new CameraSource
    .Builder(this, _barcodeDetector)
    .SetRequestedPreviewSize(250, 250)
    .SetAutoFocusEnabled(true)
    .Build();
surfaceView.Holder.AddCallback(this);
_barcodeDetector.SetProcessor(this);

public void ReceiveDetections(Detections detections)
{
    try
    {
        SparseArray barcodes = detections.DetectedItems;
        if (barcodes.Size() != 0)
        {
            string barcode = ((Barcode)barcodes.ValueAt(0)).RawValue;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Firbase ML kit or Google vision api ? if you are Using MLkit  and getting this issue then go for Zxing

Comment: I am using Google Vision API

Comment: Use FireBase MLKit  because Google vision api is deprecated now. Mlkit is upgraded version of this

Comment: Code 128 is the spec code, GS1-128 is the app code.

Comment: Is Mlkit available for xamarin? I tried using Zxing but its a pain to customize the UI. Which is why I had opted for Google vision API.

Comment: @SushiHangover So does that men Google vision API doe not support GS1-128?

Comment: @Arti GS1-128 is a part of the Code 128 spec (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128) so your GS1-128 barcodes should seen as Code 128 (as you stated it does in your question). The Vision API is being retired and for new code you really should start using FireBase's ML Kit (it is in "beta" but I've had no issues using it) and by using the Camera2 api (YUV output format) and dropping extra frames during the model execution, you can get near real-time detection/decoding...